# How to create an arbitrary link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

link_to and helpers use the names of my models and their IDs while I want to have a couple of different, arbitrary, variables in my link. I have no problems to route them, I actually keep the default routing as well, but I suddenly stuck that I cannot easily generate an arbitrary link. For instance I want to have a link like ":name_of_board/:post_number", where :name_of_board and :post_number are variables set by me, and when I use link_to I get instead "posts/:id", where "posts" it's the name of the controller. While it's not hard to use an arbitrary id like

```
link_to 'Reply', :controller => "posts", :action => "show", :id => number
```

I cannot get how I can get rid of "posts". So, is there an easy way to generate a link by variables or to convert a string into link? Sure, I can add other queries to the line above, but it will make the link even more ugly, like "posts/:id?name_of_board=:name_of_board".

Comment: would be helpful to see your routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional routes for your posts resource in your routes.rb, or make standalone named routes:

```
resources :posts do
  get ':name_of_board/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :with_name_of_board
end

get ':name_of_board/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :board
```

Now this

```
@name_of_board = "foo"
@post_id = 5

link_to 'Reply', posts_with_name_of_board_path(@name_of_board, @post_id)

link_to 'Reply', board_path(@name_of_board, @post_id)
```

would link to `/posts/foo/5` and `/foo/5` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should first edit your route entry, for example a classic show route is the follow:

```
get "post/:id" => "post#show", :as => :post
# + patch, put, delete have the same link but with different method
```

And you can call it with the following helper

```
link_to "Show the post", post_path(:id => @post.id)
```

You can edit or create a new entry in the routes, applying the parameters you want to use, e.g.:

```
get "post/:id/:my_platform" => "post#show", :as => :post_custom
```

Then

```
link_to "Show the post with custom", post_custom_path(:id => @post.id, :my_platform => "var")
```

Finally, the link generated for this last entry is for example:

```
 "/post/3/var"
```

Even in this situation, you can add some other params not defined in the routes, e.g.:

```
link_to "Show post with params", post_custom_path(:id => @post.id, :my_platform => "var", :params1 => "var1", :params2 => "var2")
=> "/post/3/var?params1=var1&params2=var2"
```

RoR match your variable defined in the routes when you render a link (remember that these variables are mandatory), but you can ever add other vars that come at the end of the url (`"?...&.."`)